# Prove $Y=X$ almost surely given they have the same distribution and $Y$ is an increasing function of $X$

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics

If $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution and $Y=g(X)$ where $g$ is monotonically increasing, then $Y=X$ almost surely. It seems obvious, but how to prove it?

Comment: are they integrable ?

Comment: @StratosFair If it is true for integrable variables I think you can extend to non-integrable without too much difficulty by truncating.

Comment: Although I think this statement is probably true, could you please add where did you see it?

Comment: For questions like this, I usually consider the square-integrable case first, and try to show that $E[(X-Y)^2] = 2(E[X^2] - E[XY]) = 0$. The integrable case usually follows by approximation arguments.

Comment: "have the same distribution" this means that the cdf is equal in every point?

Comment: @Zhanxiong I didn’t see it anywhere; it’s my own observation

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus yes, the cumulative distribution functions are equal

Comment: @StratosFair yes they are integrable

Comment: @YashaswiMohanty If $g$ and $F$ (the CDF of $X$) are strictly increasing, then it is easy to prove.

Comment: I would have thought that  $F(g(x))=F(x)$ for all $x$, so $\mathbb P(x \lt X \le g(x))=0$ and $\mathbb P(g(x) \lt X \le x) =0$ for all $x$.  Do this imply $\mathbb P(Y =X)=1- \mathbb P(X <g(X)) - \mathbb P(g(X)<X) =0$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The idea is clear in a picture:** if we were to sketch the graph of the distribution function $F_X$ of $X,$ we may conceive of $g$ as locally shifting all horizontal points various amounts (but always consistently, never allowing any overlapping), thereby distorting the graph of $F_X$ into the graph of $F_Y$.  The condition $F_X=F_Y$ means that this distortion is *purely horizontal:* the height $F_X(t)$ at any point $t$ must remain the same as the height $F_Y(t).$  Thus, if $g(t)\ne t,$ **$(t,F_X(t))$ and $(g(t),F_X(g(t))$ are always part of a horizontal line segment in the graph of $F_X$:** but over that segment, $X$ has zero probability (because its distribution function $F$ does not change over that segment).

The only real issue is showing that it's legitimate to sum these zero probabilities over potentially infinitely many such segments.  This is related to a basic property of real numbers.

---

**Let's reason from the definitions.**

- $X$ is a real-valued random variable. Let $F_X(x) = \Pr(X\le x)$ be
  its distribution function.
- We are given $g:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ where $s\lt t$ implies
  $g(s)\lt g(t)$ ($g$ is *increasing*) and $Y = g\circ X$ is also a
  random variable.

**The condition in the statement, that $F_X = F_Y,$** therefore means that for all numbers $t,$

$$\Pr(X\le t) = F_X(t) = F_Y(t) = \Pr(Y\le t) = \Pr(g(X)\lt t).\tag{*}$$

To adopt an economical notation, when $a$ and $b$ are real numbers, $(a,b)$ is the open interval with endpoints at $a$ and $b$ (even when $ b\lt a$).  When $a=b,$ this is the empty set.  Condition $(*)$ implies that for all numbers $t$ where $g(t)\le t,$

$$\Pr(X\in (g(t), t]) = \Pr(X\in (-\infty, t] \setminus (-\infty, g(t)]) = F_X(t) - F_Y(t) = 0.\tag{**}$$

The same result obtains when $g(t)\gt t.$  Thus, writing $\mathcal A$ for the event $X\ne Y,$ we may characterize it as

$$X\ne Y:\ X\in \mathcal A = \bigcup_{t\in\mathbb R}\, (t, g(t))$$

This is an *uncountable* union of open intervals: no axioms or theorems of probability permit us to draw any conclusion about its probability directly.  The key is to recall that $\mathbb R$ is *locally compact:* this implies that on any bounded closed interval, such as $[-n,n]$ for positive integers $n,$ a *finite* number of real numbers $t_{n,i},$ $i=1,2,\ldots, N(n),$ can be found for which

$$\mathcal A \cap [-n,n] = \bigcup_{i=1}^{N(n)}\, (t_{n,i}, g(t_i)).$$

(See the [Heine-Borel theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem).)

Therefore the probability of this event is not greater than the sum of the probabilities of the intervals of which it is comprised and since by $(**)$ each of those intervals is contained within a zero-probability event,

$$\Pr(\mathcal A \cap [-n,n]) = 0.$$

Taking the *countable* union of these sets for $n=1,2,3,\ldots,$ and applying the sigma-additivity property of probability shows

$$\Pr(\mathcal A) = 0 = \Pr(X\ne Y),$$

*QED.*

Comment: Conjuring up a picture couldn't be more powerful. This answer bears the testament to that. +1.

Comment: *"The only real issue is showing that it's legitimate to sum these zero probabilities over potentially infinitely many such segments."* Your picture is very nice, but the issue is not entirely settled, especially because that infinite sum over zero probabilities. I myself was looking into the Cantor distribution or ways to express functions $g(x)$ that express a number in terms of the next number while that number changes by zero (a function that doesn't exist, see : [finding the next rational number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1468023/)). Your proof that solves this is very cool